# Playing Offline HLS with AES-128 encryption iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, http-live-streaming

I want to integrate offline HLS in iOS through `AVFoundation`.
I have an encrypted HLS with simple AES-128 and it doesn't want to play in offline mode, I was trying to integrate `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`, but don't know how to integrate `applicationCertificate` and `contentKeyFromKeyServerModuleWithSPCData` that are in  https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/ examples. I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong. It is a sample `AES-128 encryption`, not even `DRM`.

Without the internet, `AVPlayer` is still trying to get `encryption key` through `GET` request.
It would be great if someone succeeded to save the encrypted key locally and somehow gave it to `AVPlayer` together with `AVURLAsset`.

Did someone manage to integrate this?

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Comment: yeap I am writing right now answer for my question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have written to apple support and their responses weren't new for me. Information that they provided to me I got from wwdc videos and documentation before I started a conversation with them. (https://developer.apple.com/streaming/fps/)

Further, I will describe how I achieve to play HLS in offline mode with AES-128 encryption. The [Example On Github](https://github.com/Cyklet/VidLoader) describes the below process.
Take care AVDownloadTask doesn’t work on the simulator so you should have a device for this implementation. 
At the beginning, you need a stream URL.

**Step 1:**
Before creating AVURLAsset we should take stream URL and change scheme to an invalid one (example: *https* -> *fakehttps*, I did it through URLComponents) and assign AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate to the new created url asset. All this changes force AVAssetDownloadTask to call:

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
}
```

(it is calling because AVFoundation see an invalid URL and doesn’t know what to do with it)

**Step 2:**
When delegate is called we should check that url is that one that we had before. We need to change back scheme to valid one and create a simple URLSession with it. We will get first .m3u8 file that should be like:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1697588,RESOLUTION=1280x720,FRAME-RATE=23.980,CODECS="mp4a"
https://avid.avid.net/avid/information_about_stream1
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1132382,RESOLUTION=848x480,FRAME-RATE=23.980,CODECS="mp4a"
https://avid.avid.net/avid/information_about_stream2
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=690409,RESOLUTION=640x360,FRAME-RATE=23.980,CODECS="mp4a"
https://avid.avid.net/avid/information_about_stream3
```

**Step 3:**
Parse all needed information from this data and change all *https* schemes to invalid one *fakehttps*
Now you should setup AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest from *shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource* delegate like:

```
loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentType = response.mimeType
loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = response.expectedContentLength
loadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: modifiedData)
loadingRequest.finishLoading()
downloadTask?.resume()
```

where: response -> response from URLSession,  modifiedData -> data with changed URL’s

Resume your download task and return true in *shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource* delegate

**Step 4:** 
If everything will be ok AVAssetDownloadDelegate will fire with:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session assetDownloadTask:(AVAssetDownloadTask *)assetDownloadTask didResolveMediaSelection:(AVMediaSelection *)resolvedMediaSelection NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0) {
}
```

**Step 5:**
We have changed all *https* to *fakehttps* when AVFoundation will select best media stream URL, *shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource* will trigger again with one of the URL from first .m3u8

**Step 6:**
When delegate is called again we should check that url is that one that we needed. Change again fake scheme to a valid one and create a simple URLSession with this url. We will get second .m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://avid.avid.net/avid/key”
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXTINF:6.006,
https://avid.avid.net/avid/information_about_stream1
#EXTINF:4.713,
https://avid.avid.net/avid/information_about_stream2
#EXTINF:10.093,
https://avid.avid.net/avid/information_about_stream3
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

**Step 7:** 
Parse second .m3u8 file and take all information that you need from it, also take a look on

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://avid.avid.net/avid/key”
```

We have URL for encryption key

**Step 8:**
Before sending some information back to AVAssetDownloadDelegate we need to download the key from the server and save it locally on the device. After this you should change URI=`https://avid.avid.net/avid/key` from second .m3u8 to an invalid URI=`fakehttps://avid.avid.net/avid/key`, or maybe a local file path where you have saved your local key. 
Now you should setup AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest from *shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource* delegate smth. like:

```
loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentType = response.mimeType
loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = response.expectedContentLength
loadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: modifiedData)
loadingRequest.finishLoading()
downloadTask?.resume()
```

where: response -> response from URLSession,  modifiedData -> data with changed URL’s

Resume your download task and return true in shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource delegate (Same as on Step 3)

**Step 9:**
Of course, when download task will try to create request with modified `URI=` that again is not a valid one *shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource* will trigger again. In this case, you should detect this and create new data with your persistent key(the key that you saved locally. Take care here `contentType` should be `AVStreamingKeyDeliveryPersistentContentKeyType` without it AVFoundation doesn’t understand that this contains key).

```
loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentType = AVStreamingKeyDeliveryPersistentContentKeyType
loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = keyData.count
loadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: keyData)
loadingRequest.finishLoading()
downloadTask?.resume()
```

**Step 10:**
Chunks will be downloaded automatically by AVFoudnation.
When download is finished this delegate will be called:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
}
```

You should save `location` somewhere, when you want to play stream from device you should create AVURLAsset from this `location` URL

All this information is saved locally by AVFoundation so next time when you will try to play local content in offline AVURLAsset delegate will be called because of URI=`fakehttps://avid.avid.net/avid/key`, that is an invalid link, here you will do Step 9 again and video will play in offline mode.

This works for me if anyone knows better implementation I will be glad to know.

[Example On Github](https://github.com/Cyklet/VidLoader)

Comment: Thanks buddy I was facing another issue with AES-128 bit HLS  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097856/avplayer-stops-playing-aes-encrypted-offline-hls-video-in-online-mode/46300060#46300060  Your answer gave me some hint about what to do.

Comment: Would be very helpful if you could share complete class or project code. Thanks!

Comment: @Sikander did you find the solution?

Comment: @AmritTiwari yes. Had to implement AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate finally.

Comment: @Sikander can you please provide me a solution? I am stuck, if you provide me with a solution then it will be a great help to me.

Comment: @Sikander Hello, can you help me to play downloaded AES-128 bit encrypted video on offline?

Comment: @Sikander here is the sample code https://github.com/tiwariammit/HLSVideoDownloader

Comment: @Sikander used for initialization of AVURLAsset, progress of the current state.

Comment: I followed the above steps but chunks are not getting downloaded. First chunk starts to download and then it fails also `didFinishDownloadingTo` method is getting called after the failure of first chunk.

Comment: @Cyklet: I am looking for same approach, Can you please provide sample code for this. It will be helpful for every one.

Comment: I have followed all the steps. Final it is calling below delegate method. So is this procedure still is in working state. Please let me know.

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {

Comment: I know that it can be too late but I just added in my answer a link https://github.com/Cyklet/VidLoader with an example of how this process has been implemented.

Comment: @Cyklet after days trying to resolve, you finally saved my life! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Cyklet Answer helped me a ton! Thanks.

There is however an additional step I had to do to get hls streaming to work.

---

When using `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` [apples documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloadingcontentinformationrequest/1388529-contenttype?language=objc):

> **contentType**
>
> Before finishing loading an AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest instance, if its contentInformationRequest property is not nil, set the value of this property to a UTI indicating the type of data contained by the requested resource.

When trying to implement HLS Streaming there are two [UTIs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers) that may be used (as far as I know...).

- `AVStreamingKeyDeliveryPersistentContentKeyType`

  - `"com.apple.streamingkeydelivery.persistentcontentkey"`
- `AVStreamingKeyDeliveryContentKeyType`

  - `"com.apple.streamingkeydelivery.contentkey"`

Check [allowedContentTypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloadingcontentinformationrequest/2936886-allowedcontenttypes?language=objc) what UTI to use. See possible implementation below:

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {

....
   var contentType = AVStreamingKeyDeliveryPersistentContentKeyType
            
   if let allowedContentType = contentInformationRequest.allowedContentTypes?.first{
       if allowedContentType == AVStreamingKeyDeliveryContentKeyType{
           contentType = AVStreamingKeyDeliveryContentKeyType
       }
    }
....
}
```