# AVPlayer Stops Playing AES encrypted offline HLS Video in online mode

Tags: ios, aes, avplayer, http-live-streaming, avplayeritem

I have written a code to download HLS video and play it in offline mode.
This code works fine for encoded video. Now I have a video which is AES encrypted and we are having custom encryption key for it. After downloading AES encrypted HLS video I am using below given code to supply key for decryption of video.

```
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest {

NSString *scheme = loadingRequest.request.URL.scheme;

if ([scheme isEqualToString:@"ckey"]) {

    NSString *request = loadingRequest.request.URL.host;
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:request];

    if (data) {
        [loadingRequest.dataRequest respondWithData:data];
        [loadingRequest finishLoading];
    } else {
        // Data loading fail
    }
}
return NO; }
```

I am intercepting a request for a key and passing key stored in UserDefaults for decryption.

**This AES encrypted HLS video with custom key plays well when my device's wifi or data connection is off.**

**If I start playing this video when my device's wifi or data connection is enabled or if
I enable my device's wifi or data connection while playing video; video stops playing immediately without any error and never plays again.**

I have checked accessLog and errorLog of playerItem but haven't found anything helpful.

To provide a custom URL key after downloading of HLS content I am updating a content of .m3u8 file by replacing

> URI="..."

string with

> URI="ckey://..."

Is this a correct way to provide key for AES encrypted video?

and what could be the reason of this behaviour and how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: @AmritTiwari below given answer is work around for this issue you can try this.

Comment: I can figure out the solution can you please help me?

Comment: @AmritTiwari Yes tell me what is your problem.

Comment: I can't play downloaded encrypted video in offline mode. But everything will work fine when the device is in online, I know it is the problem of unable to insert decryption key. So can you please help me to shot out this problem?

Comment: @AmritTiwari I was also having the same problem and I solved it. Can you log separate question for it so I can answer on that. So it will be helpful to others as well. Just a log new question and give me its link. I will answer on that.

Comment: you can also make a sample project and share its GitHub link so it will be helpful to others who are seeking it.

Comment: you can also post the answer here.

Comment: @AmritTiwari I will update my answer for your query, just give me one or two days.

Comment: thank you. Can I get your contact so that I can direct message you?

Comment: @MARTINI have made demo app. URL : https://github.com/tiwariammit/HLSVideoDownloader

Comment: @AmritTiwari I have updated my answer just check it. If have any query please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this issue. Rough package structure of downloaded HLS video is like given below:

```
HLS.movpkg 
 |_ 0-12345
    |_ 123.m3u8
    |_ StreamInfoBoot.xml
    |_ StreamInfoRoot.xml
    |_ <>.frag
 |_ boot.xml
```

1. boot.xml contains network URL for HLS (which is https: based)
2. StreamBootInfo.xml contains mapping between HLS URL (which is https: based) and .frag file downloaded locally.

In offline mode HLS video was playing perfectly. But when network connection was enabled it was referring to https: URL instead of local .frag files.

I replaced https: scheme in these files with custom scheme (fakehttps:) to restrict AVPlayer going online for resources.

This thing solved my issue but I don't know the exact reason behind it and how HLS is played by AVPlayer.

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670774/playing-offline-hls-with-aes-128-encryption-ios) and got some idea so tried something .

**I am updating this answer further to explain how to play encrypted video in offline mode.**

> 1. Get the key required for video decryption.
> 2. Save that key some where.
>
> You can save that key as `NSData` or `Data` object in `UserDefault` I am using video file name as key to save key data in UserDefaults.
>
> 3. Use `FileManager` API to iterate over all the files inside `.movpkg`.
> 4. Get the content of each `.m3u8` file and replace `URI="some key url"` with URI="ckey://keyusedToSaveKeyDataInUserDefaults"
>
> You can refer code given below for this process.

```
  if let url = asset.asset?.url, let data = data {
            
            let keyFileName = "\(asset.contentCode!).key"
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: keyFileName)
            
            do {
                
                // ***** Create key file *****
                let keyFilePath = "ckey://\(keyFileName)"
                
                let subDirectories = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: url,
                                                                                 includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsSubdirectoryDescendants)
                
                for url in subDirectories {
                    
                    var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false
                    
                    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: url.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
                        
                        if isDirectory.boolValue {
                            
                            let path = url.path as NSString
                            
                            let folderName = path.lastPathComponent
                            let playlistFilePath = path.appendingPathComponent("\(folderName).m3u8")
                            
                            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: playlistFilePath) {
                                
                                var fileContent = try String.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: playlistFilePath))
                                
                                let stringArray = self.matches(for: "URI=\"(.+?)\"", in: fileContent)
                                
                                for pattern in stringArray {
                                    fileContent = fileContent.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: "URI=\"\(keyFilePath)\"")
                                }
                                
                                try fileContent.write(toFile: playlistFilePath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                            }
                            
                            let streamInfoXML = path.appendingPathComponent("StreamInfoBoot.xml")

                            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: streamInfoXML) {

                                var fileContent = try String.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: streamInfoXML))
                                fileContent = fileContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "https:", with: "fakehttps:")
                                try fileContent.write(toFile: streamInfoXML, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                            }
                        } else {

                            if url.lastPathComponent == "boot.xml" {

                                let bootXML = url.path

                                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: bootXML) {

                                    var fileContent = try String.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: bootXML))
                                    fileContent = fileContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "https:", with: "fakehttps:")
                                    try fileContent.write(toFile: bootXML, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                userInfo[Asset.Keys.state] = Asset.State.downloaded.rawValue
                
                // Update download status to db
                let user = RoboUser.sharedObject()
                let sqlDBManager = RoboSQLiteDatabaseManager.init(databaseManagerForCourseCode: user?.lastSelectedCourse)
                sqlDBManager?.updateContentDownloadStatus(downloaded, forContentCode: asset.contentCode!)
               
                self.notifyServerAboutContentDownload(asset: asset)
                
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: AssetDownloadStateChangedNotification, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
            } catch  {
            }
        }

func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
    
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

**This will update your download package structure for playing encrypted video in offline mode.**

**Now last thing to do is implement below given method of AVAssetResourceLoader class as follows**

```
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest {
    
    NSString *scheme = loadingRequest.request.URL.scheme;
    
    if ([scheme isEqualToString:@"ckey"]) {
        
        NSString *request = loadingRequest.request.URL.host;
        NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:request];
        
        if (data) {
            loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.contentType = AVStreamingKeyDeliveryPersistentContentKeyType;
            loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.byteRangeAccessSupported = YES;
            loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.contentLength = data.length;
            [loadingRequest.dataRequest respondWithData:data];
            [loadingRequest finishLoading];
        } else {
            // Data loading fail
        }
    }
    
    return YES;
}
```

This method will provide key to video while playing to decrypt it.

Comment: thanks you for updating your answer and can you tell me what will matches method do in your code?

Comment: @AmritTiwari I have updated this answer with matches() method. It just checks for regular expression.

Comment: Can you please tell me process how you had done. I am confused about applying encryption key and when to set resourceLoader of AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate?

Comment: can you please help me?

Comment: @Martin, thanks man! I wish I could treat you coffee!

Comment: @AbdullahMd.Zubair I am glad that this answer helped you. :)

Comment: @Martin, Thank you so much for the post, I have followed same but still not able to play offline Could you please help me

Comment: @Paresh.P, can you tell what exactly you have done?

Comment: @Martin
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {}
In above function when download finish, I have local url for downloaded audio file.
I use same local url and key data to process the step 4 as you mentioned in code

Comment: and using this key data in 
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest {}

Still audio did not started to play offline.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tWVJxFRWuob9AT5nKML88Amd5xWOJnnc-_HF7OI8Bdg/edit?usp=sharing
Here is the code that I have used

Comment: @Martin anything you can help with?