# Can't figure out HLS download

Tags: swift, swift4, http-live-streaming

I've tried the following:

```
func setupAssetDownload() {
    // Create new background session configuration.
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "123124123152")

    // Create a new AVAssetDownloadURLSession with background configuration, delegate, and queue
    let downloadSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: configuration,
                                                assetDownloadDelegate: self,
                                                delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let url = URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8")// HLS Asset URL
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url!)

    // Create new AVAssetDownloadTask for the desired asset
    let downloadTask = downloadSession.makeAssetDownloadTask(asset: asset,
                                                             assetTitle: "assetTitle",
                                                             assetArtworkData: nil,
                                                             options: nil)
    // Start task and begin download
    print(downloadTask.debugDescription)
    downloadTask?.resume()
}
```

and implemented

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("didFinishDownloadingTo \(location.relativePath)")
    playOfflineAsset()
}
```

but the delegate method `didFinishDownloadingTo` is never called.

Also added `didCompleteWithError` delegate with no success.
My class is conforming to `AVAssetDownloadDelegate`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54493233/10758374

Answer (score 0):

**AVAssetDownloadURLSession** always work with real device only..So in your case its seems like you are tried on simulator.

Please go with **Real device**