# Unable to play downloaded HLS content while internet is not available

Tags: swift, avplayer, offline, http-live-streaming, playback

I am working on Downloading and playing HLS content, To download the HLS I am using following code

```
func downloadTask() {

let videoUrl =  URL(string: "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8")!

    configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: downloadIdentifier)
    downloadSession = AVAssetDownloadURLSession(configuration: configuration!, assetDownloadDelegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(videoUrl.lastPathComponent)


    var urlComponents = URLComponents(
        url: videoUrl,
        resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false
        )!
    urlComponents.scheme = "https"
    do {
        let asset = try AVURLAsset(url: urlComponents.url!)
        asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.AssetResourceLoaderDelegateQueue"))

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            assetDownloadTask = downloadSession!
                .makeAssetDownloadTask(
                    asset: asset,
                    assetTitle: "RG-TVVideo",
                    assetArtworkData: nil,
                    options: nil
            )
            APP_DELEGATE.isProgressRunning = true
            assetDownloadTask?.resume()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    } catch { print("Erorr while parsing the URL.") }
}
```

Download finished

```
 func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let storageManager = AVAssetDownloadStorageManager.shared()
        let newPolicy = AVMutableAssetDownloadStorageManagementPolicy()
        newPolicy.expirationDate = Date()
        newPolicy.priority = .important
        let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())
        let assetURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(location.relativePath)
        storageManager.setStorageManagementPolicy(newPolicy, for: assetURL)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(location.relativePath, forKey: "videoPath")
        strDownloadStatus = "5"
        let dictVideoInfo = ["strDownloadStatus" : "5","VideoID":self.strID]

// Here I am Storing Downloaded location in to database 
            DBManager.shared.updateVideoStatus(strVideoID: APP_DELEGATE.arrTempVideoIds.object(at: 0) as! String, strStatus: "5", strSavePath: location.relativePath) { (status) in }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init("UpdateProgress"), object: self.percentageComplete, userInfo: dictVideoInfo)
        }

    }
}
```

Now I am trying to get Video path from the location which is stored in Database and trying to play it offline(Without Internet) using following code

```
  func setLocalPlayer(strDownloadPath: String) {

    let strDownloadPath = “”

    //Getting path from database
    DBManager.shared.getDownloadedPath(videoID:  VideoID) { (strPath) in
        strDownloadPath = strPath
    }

    activityIndicator.isHidden = false

    let baseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())
    let assetURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(strDownloadPath)
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: assetURL)

    //        if let cache = asset.assetCache, cache.isPlayableOffline {
    //            let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: assetURL)
    asset.resourceLoader.preloadsEligibleContentKeys = true

    asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.AssetResourceLoaderDelegateQueue"))
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    avPlayerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: playerContainer.frame.width, height: playerContainer.frame.height)
    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = .resize

    avPlayerLayer.player = avPlayer

    playerContainer.layer.addSublayer(avPlayerLayer)

    let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.01, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    timeObserver = avPlayer?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { elapsedTime in
        self.updateVideoPlayerState()

        if self.avPlayer != nil {
            self.bufferState()
        }
    })

    self.slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "slider_dot"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
    resetTimer()

    avPlayer.play()
    isPlaying = true
    //        }
}
```

**NOTE:** This code is working fine when internet is on

I have referred following links

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/HTTPLiveStreaming/HTTPLiveStreaming.html

https://assist-software.net/snippets/how-play-encrypted-http-live-streams-offline-avfoundation-ios-using-swift-4

[Downloading and playing offline HLS Content - iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424263/downloading-and-playing-offline-hls-content-ios-10)

Please guide what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Khush, I know I'm late, but which error do you have ?
You can check AVPlayer error with command : `po avPlayer.currentItem?.errorLog()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if it's your error, but for further readings :

Don't do `newPolicy.expirationDate = Date()` it's a mistake. According to [Advances in HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/504) 2017 WWDC session, it will delete your file as soon as possible.

Before playing your offline playback, you can check if it's still on your device in Settings -> General -> Storage -> MyApp

> The expiration date property is there in case your asset at some point
> becomes no longer eligible to be played. For instance, you may find
> that you may be in a situation where a particular show may be leaving
> your catalog, you no longer have rights to stream it.
>
> If that's the case you can set the expiration date and it will be sort of bumped up
> in the deletion queue. So, using it is fairly straight forward.